# How can i append and read divide arithmetic operator in JSON url?

Tags: java, json

I have a J SON URL like http://echo.jsontest.com/Operand1/10/Operand2/5/Operator/+
I am writing a java program to read the operands and operator from URL and perform the arithmetic operations,It is working fine for every operator but for divide operator(/) it seems it cannot read the operator.Any Ideas why and how to solve it

Comment: As you probably noticed `/` is part of URL semantics, which splits its contexts. You probably should encode it, for instance with `URLEncoder.encode("/", "UTF-8")` which will return `%2F`.

Answer (score 0):

How can you define and add two variables in a json document?

```
 {
 "fName":"Asdfg",
 "lName":"Lkjjh",
 "Operator":"+",
 "fullName":$fName+$Operator+$lName
```

}

or You have defined a formula Schema
   `{
     "fullName":$fName+' '+$lName
   }`